# Implementing Generic Extension Method for Generic Type

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

If you're implementing generic extension method for generic class is there a better way?
Because it would be natural to call func2 exactly as `func1<V>()` rather than `func2<T, V>()` i.e. to omit T parameter and call it like `func2<V>()`

```
public class A<T> where T : class {

    public V func1<V>() {
        //func1 has access to T and V types
    }
}

public static class ExtA {

    // to implement func1 as extension method 2 generic parameters required
    // and we need to duplicate constraint on T 
    public static V func2<T, V>(this A<T> instance) where T : class {
        // func2 has access to V & T 
    }
}
```

Comment: extension methods work only on none generic static classes.

Comment: @MBen no. extension methods can be **declared** in non generic static class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `func2()` had only the generic parameter `T`, the compiler could infer it and you could call it without specifying the parameter.

But if you need both parameters, you have to specify them explicitly. Type inference is all or nothing: either it can infer all types used (and you don't have to specify them), or it can't and you have to specify all of them.

Comment: Compiler should be able to infer T for func2 anytime... so basically I would expect func2 declaration as following `public static V func2<V>(this A<T> inst)` as there is nothing but redundancy in declaring T & it's constraint

Comment: Maybe it should, but it does not. So you either have to live with that or use another language.

Comment: No doubt this should be fixed :). As if func2 declared as `public static V func2<T, V>(this A<T> inst, IList<V> list)` compiler able to infer both T & V

Answer (score 2):

In your example, class `A` does not know about `V`, it only knows `V` in the context of `func1`. So func2 cannot magically infer `V`.

Comment: question is not about inferring V but rather about inferring T for func2